# How to create a ClearCase branch to a specific directory

Tags: clearcase, branching-and-merging, config-spec

I'm trying to create a ClearCase view that obtains all files with a certain label applied.  Additionally, I would like to be able to create a branch on files checked out in the "source" directory, and only the source directory (or its subdirectories). For example, I don't want to create a branch of files in the /vob/design directory.

I have the following config spec, but no branches get created.  All checkouts occur only on the main branch.

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../my_branch/LATEST
element * /vob/source/MY_LABEL -mkbranch my_branch  # this should include subdirectories
element * MY_LABEL 
element * /main/LATEST
```

I have also tried the following, with the same unsuccessful results:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../my_branch/LATEST
element * /vob/source/... -mkbranch my_branch 
element * MY_LABEL 
element * /main/LATEST
```

Comment: I believe I found my answer:
    element * CHECKEDOUT 
    element * .../8732EIS_low_power_branch/LATEST
    element /Mag_2010_platform/8732EIS/03_Design/Software/source/... 8732EIS_REL_5_4_5 -mkbranch 8732EIS_low_power_branch 
    element * 8732EIS_REL_5_4_5 
    element * /main/LATEST

Comment: That seems to follow *precisely* what I have recommended before in my answer below. I have edited it to include your conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

See "[Config Spec](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm)": the path is the first element (usually, you see '`*`'), then you see the selection rule.

That means "`element * /vob/source/MY_LABEL`" is false and mixes path and selection rule together, which doesn't make sense for ClearCase.

Instead try:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../my_branch/LATEST
element /vob/source/* MY_LABEL -mkbranch my_branch  # this should include subdirectories
element * MY_LABEL 
element * /main/LATEST
```

The solution the [OP has found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848315/how-to-create-a-clearcase-branch-to-a-specific-directory#comment31274855_20848315) follows precisely what I recommended above:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT 
element * .../8732EIS_low_power_branch/LATEST 
element /Mag_2010_platform/8732EIS/03_Design/Software/source/... 8732EIS_REL_5_4_5 -mkbranch 8732EIS_low_power_branch 
element * 8732EIS_REL_5_4_5 element 
* /main/LATEST
```

Regarding the path in config spec, see also "[Paths in config spec element rules](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_bcfg_vwprojshrpthelrl.htm)".